# How to combine multiple PPM values to obtain overall PPM value?

Tags: statistics

On minitab, I have three materials and get a predicted failure rate in parts per million (PPM) for each material.

What is the combined probability of failure.

e.g.

Material 1 PPM 1000

Material 2 PPM 500

Material 3 PPM 2000

I imagine combined rate is > 2000

Is the following correct.

1. Get reliabilities [1-failure rate]
2. Multiply reliabilities together to get overall reliability
3. Subtract overall reliability from 1

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Your suggested algorithm is correct, assuming independent failures. However, in practice, the same result may be obtained by simply adding the individual failure rates, assuming each is small (i.e., much less than 1).

Comment: If it's the same as adding it's wrong, as some parts may have more than one defect e.g. out of 10 units, 3 defects were recorded.  1 unit was scrapped and nine passed.  Must be a way to handle such a scenario.